# Route ssh to specific gateway

Tags: ssh, routing

I would like to know how can I force the use of port 22 to the interface I want, any interface, Wi-Fi or Ethernet.
For example route *:22 to Wi-Fi.
I checked `route` command but it looks like it's not possible.
Any idea?
BSD or Linux commands are welcome.

Comment: I would like to nominate you for `Worst Question Ever`. Which OS? Are you connected both via ethernet and via wireless? Do you want to ssh into a LAN pc, or a WAN machine?

Comment: Sorry, I always think Linux&BSD are the only OS available, I always forgot that people run could imagine running Windows.

Comment: The ones answered in my question?

Comment: The question is already GREATLY answered, it looks like the question was not so incomprehensible.  BTW, can you **stop** editing my question with **no** improvement PLEASE!

Comment: I agree correcting `it's look likes` into `it looks like` is a small improvement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regular routing only works in terms of IP addresses and doesn't concern itself with what data (including TCP or UDP) is transferred.

---

At least on Linux, you could use [policy routing](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Adv-Routing-HOWTO/lartc.netfilter.html) for this:

1. Add a firewall rule to mark certain packets:

   ```
   iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 22 -j MARK --set-mark 1
   ```
2. Create a new routing table with your desired gateway:

   ```
   ip route add default via 192.168.0.1 dev wlan0 table 42
   ```
3. Add a policy rule to use the new routing table for marked packets:

   ```
   ip rule add fwmark 1 table 42
   ```

---

On Windows, you'll need a different approach, for example, telling the *program* to use a specific interface. Some programs have a "bind address" option, such as ssh's `-b`:

```
ssh -b 192.168.0.42 root@myserver
```

(I don't know how well it works with multiple *interfaces*, though. I have a feeling it might not.)

---

Finally, you could add a host route (via Wi-Fi) towards a specific server.

This could be extended to enabling SSH tunnelling through that server for all your other connections.