# ssh server on VM does not accept connection from outside host

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, virtual-machine, kvm-switch

I have a setup like below:
qemu as hypervisor. 
ubuntu running as a virtual machine with two network adapters:

- eth0: connected to a user network.
- ssh port is forwarded to a port
  from host OS.
- eth1: connected to a tap network that is on default NAT bridge of libvirt.

what I want to do is to be able to ssh from outside of the host to the vm using forwarded port:

- ssh username@host_ip -p forwarded_port

however, ssh command is getting timeout.

I am able to ssh from the host to the vm using forwarded port:

- ssh username@localhost -p forwarded_port

interestingly enought, when I remove the second interface that is connected to NAT network, I am able to ssh to the server from outside.
so I know for sure that firewall is not blocking anything.

what am I doing wrong? is it something related to ssh or the network?

EDIT: I figured when I set the nat interface down, ssh from outside is working.

Comment: Why are you using second interface ? If you use eth0, then you will be able to connect to it from outside without that eth1

Comment: What command did you use to forward the port? Is that forward listening on all interfaces? Is the destination unambiguous?

Comment: @Andy I use port forwarding for qemu as a netdev argument. I can even see the packet on the VM using tcpdump. I think ssh server tries to respond to it through the default gateway which is in the other network.

Comment: Sounds like you found your problem. You need to mess with `ip route` priorities on your guest to make eth0's gateway the preferred default gateway.

Comment: @Andy this is what I don't want to do. I want to be able to send only ssh traffic through the user type network (eth0 in the example), which is not my default gateway network. is this possible?

Comment: Create a special route table for your ssh traffic: https://superuser.com/questions/1010513/